# Visual Studio 2013 Optional Features to Install

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2013, feature-selection

I am installing visual studio 2013 professional edition on my development box and have question on what features need to install ..

I am going to develop a MVC or Web Forms Web Application which communicates to SQL Server 2005
[image]
I want to install only features that are required for development, please let me know if my understanding is correct

**Blend for Visual Studio**   --- NOT REQUIRED as I am not going to use HTML5 or XAML or WPF or Silverlight

**LightSwitch** -- NOT REQUIRED as I am developing only Web Application, nothing related to Desktop /Cloud

**Microsoft Foundation Classes for C++** -- I am going to use C# 4.0, do I need this ?

**Microsoft Office Developer Tools** -- Not Required , I am not going to develop anything related to sharepoint OR MS Office,  BUT I NEED TO CREATE CSV TEXT FILES, READING CSV Files -- I Don't need this right ??

**Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools**  Not Required -- it installs SQL Server 2012 components, but my applications talks to SQL Server 2005 -- I might use Entity Framework , do I need this ?

**Microsoft Web  Developer Tools** -- Required

**Silver light Development Kit** --  Not Required Application does not have any Silver light development/features --

Comment: SQL Server Data Tools supports modeling your SQL Server 2005 database, automating deployment to it and storing your database definition in source control. It's compatible with 2005 and up. If you are actively developing the database (rather than just communicating with it) then it may prove useful. Note that most of its components are actually installed anyhow since Server Explorer uses it to connect to SQL Server databases, so there's very little difference in install size if you choose not to install it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need Microsoft Foundation Classes for C++ (MFC). You likely will not need SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) either. You don't need the Microsoft Office Developer Tools either because what you've specified will not require Office interop.

So in other words the only thing you need is the Microsoft Web Developer Tools.

Comment: thanks for your response. Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools inclueds "Entity Framework Designer"  -- can I just install Entity Framework Designer ? And also in future if I need any other options listed above I should be able to install by using modify/repair option from control panlel, am I right ?..